# How to do perspective projection "parallax" but without changing the scale or offset of objects?

Tags: opengl, directx, projection, parallax, perspective

The problem:
I am making a 2D game with parallax effect but I am using 3d space so am not simulating the parallax but letting the perspective projection take care of it for me. now the problem i have my own game editor where I design the levels, in this editor I use just images and I set a Z value for each layer. however I want the layers to show in the game engine exactly as I set them in the game editor, in short I want perspective projection to do parallax but without changing their scale or offset/position.

obvious solution is to scale them up and offset them but the problem how to calculate their offset?
with scaling I tried object->Scale(object.Z/view.Z) and seems to return them to their real size but their positions are still wrong. 
I tried object->setPositionX(object->getPosition().x*(object.Z/view.Z)) and seems to be aligned except they all seems shifted.

I have tried unprojecting and tried to convert from world matrix to screen matrix and find some ratios and so on.

How could this be done in an elegant/mathematical way?

Answer (score 1):

Perspective projection will always scale your geometry, if it doesn't it's not perspective. You can easily simultate parallax if you set the projection to orthographic and scroll geometry that is farther away by a larger amount.
I don't know what kind of game you are making, but for this example's sake, let's say it's a mario clone. When you press the right arrow key, mario moves right by X amount and your camera moves at the same speed. You can let all geometry that is not part of the direct level mesh (The same "layer" as mario) scroll by X*object.z amount (you might have to adjust that value) to make objects that are closer scroll slower and objects that are farther scroll faster.

Comment: thanks for your answer, however I dont want to switch to ortho projection because i still want to be able to add real 3d objects to the scene. i have made parallax before and i know its easier to just translate other layers to simulate it. but what i want to achieve here is to pre-calaculate the required size of an image that if it was to be projected it would give the real image size as in the game editor.

Comment: @user2017987 You say you have a 2d game, perhaps you can set the projection matrix to ortho, draw all your "2d" stuff (the layers), then switch to perspective and draw your 3d geometry?

Comment: you have a point here i will give it a try, however i still believe its possible to be done if i just can get the formula right.